# Prove $n^4+4$ is composite for all integers $n>1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

I've recently started self-studying through Niven's *Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* and had questions on a few of the problems. In particular, I'm not sure how to show that $n^4+4$ is composite for all $n>1$. I've tried my usual go-to methods of induction and breaking it up into cases by congruence classes. What are some other angles of attack? I always love a new way to take on a problem.

On a side note, to check my work or give me a hint when stuck I couldn't find any solutions for this textbook. (I've seen the "Hints" and "Answers" sections at the end, but comparatively few problems are addressed there.) Can anyone help me find a reference?

Thank you!

Comment: Congruence classes definitely work -- which modulus did you use?  Have you tried others?  (Hint:  Generating the first few values of this polynomial should offer a pretty compelling suggested modulus!)

Comment: See [Sophie-Germain identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain#Honors_in_number_theory).

Comment: @CamMcLeman Reducing modulo 5 works when $n \not \equiv 0 \pmod 5$. But what if $n \equiv 0 \pmod 5$?

Comment: Oops!  Good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the specific example that you give [completing the square yields a difference of squares,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1260952/242) therefore it yields a factorization, which is easily proved nontrivial. More generally

$$\begin{eqnarray} \overbrace{\color{#0a0}{n^4+4k^4}}^{\rm incomplete\ \large \Box}\!\! &=\,& \overbrace{\color{#0a0}{(n^2\!+2k^2)^2}}^{\rm\!\!\! completed\ \large \Box\!\!\!}\!\!-\!(\color{#c00}{2nk})^2\ \ \text{so factoring this} \textit{ difference of squares}\\[.2em]
 &\,=\,& (n^2\!+2k^2\ -\,\ \color{#c00}{2nk})\,(n^2\!+2k^2+\,\color{#c00}{2nk})\\[.2em]
&\,=\,&(\underbrace{(n-k)^2}_{\rm\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! complete\ the\ square\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}\ +\ \,k^2)\ \ \underbrace{((n+k)^2}_{\rm\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! complete\ the\ square\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!} +\,k^2)\\ \end{eqnarray}$$

which is composite if $\,|k| > 1\,$ or $\,n\neq \pm1,0\,$ since then both factors have form $\,j^2+k^2\ge 2.$

This is sometimes called the [Sophie Germain Identity](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Sophie_Germain_Identity)
.