# Is there a theorem or name for the factorization $x^4 + 4 = (x^2 + 2x + 2)(x^2 - 2x + 2)$

Tags: terminology, factoring

I see a common pattern where the sum of two terms to the fourth power can be reduced to two quadratic factors. Here is an example.

$ x^4 + 4 = (x^2 + 2x + 2)(x^2 - 2x + 2) $

I mean I get that it can be obtained through adding and subtracting a term so that it can become a difference of two squares and then factoring it. But I would like to know if there like a name or law that represents this concept. I think I recall seeing something to that effect in Wikipedia but right now I can't seem to find it again.

Comment: The product of what you wrote is $x^4+4$

Comment: Oh, sorry. I will correct this.

Comment: This is [Sophie Germain's identity](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/SophieGermainIdentity.shtml)

Comment: Is $4$ really a fourth product if we’re factoring over the integers?

Comment: I think you mean the sum of a fourth power and four times a fourth power

Comment: $4$ not a number to the fourth power.

Comment: **Exact Dupe** of [Prove $n^4+4$ is composite for all integers $n\ge 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171233/prove-n44-is-composite-for-all-integers-n1) or, more genera;lly, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1260952/242).

Comment: It’s not an exact duplicate, because this question asked for the name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to know if there [is] a name or law that represents this concept.

The sum of a fourth power and **four times** a fourth power, of which you gave an example,

can be factored using what is called [Sophie Germain's identity](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/SophieGermainIdentity.shtml):

$a^{4} + 4b^{4} = (a^{2}+2b^{2}-2ab)(a^{2}+2b^{2}+2ab).$